# What is Fubini's lemma?

Tags: real-analysis

Yesterday my professor talked about using "Fubini's lemma" for a proof. I told him that I know "[Fubini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem)" (exchanging double integral), but he said no, the Fubini's lemma is different from Fubini's theorem. Yesterday I was unable to ask in detail. I have searched internet and could not find this lemma. So I want to ask what on earth Fubini's lemma is?

The so-called Fubini's lemma is used to prove the following problem 1(c).
[image]

Thank you!

Comment: [Here](https://books.google.com/books?id=YDkDmQ_hdmcC&pg=PA269&lpg=PA269&dq=%22fubini's+lemma%22&source=bl&ots=MfYQduMLPo&sig=Fif__RfZXPEIRc5gR1evAb5drFw&hl=en&sa=X&ei=NOmfVZavO4OtogS5h7iwBg&ved=0CCMQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22fubini's%20lemma%22&f=false) it is!

Comment: WOW! Thanks so much!

Comment: You're welcome! My pleasure.